# How can I check if Firewall rule exists before adding a new one using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, firewall, windows-11

Here is my code:

```
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule
$par = @{
    DisplayName = "Block appvlp.exe netconns"
    Direction="Outbound"
    Protocol ="TCP" 
    Action = "block"
    Profile = "Any"
    Program = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\client\AppVLP.exe"
    Enabled = "True"
}
$par.DisplayName = "Block appvlp.exe netconns"
if (-not $rules.DisplayName.Contains($par.DisplayName)) {New-NetFirewallRule @par}
```

so far I only managed to make it check for displayname of Firewall, if it exists then don't add it.

what I want is for the Powershell script to check whether a rule with the same Displayname, allow/block criteria and Program path exists, before creating a new Firewall rule.

DisplayName is the least important criteria for me, the most important ones are the Program, its allowed/blocked state and enabled/disabled state.

I want to make the script very strict in its checking for available Firewall rules before creating a new one so that it won't create duplicate ones.

how can I add Program path and allow/block criteria to my Powershell script checks?

I tried this but it gives me an error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetFirewallRule -program "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\client\AppVLP.exe"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: you can use ```compare-object``` to compare several properties of a object in one step. But get-firewallRule does not give you all the details, e.g. to get the related port filter you have to do: ```Get-NetFirewallRule -Name [name] | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter```, or for your example ```Get-NetFirewallrule -displayname [name] |  Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter```

Comment: I rather not use display name at all as it's just a simple name and nothing else. I want to query firewall rules based on the exact executable, allow/block state, enabled/disabled state.

Comment: yes that's what I tried to explain you in my first comment. in the end you have to get the rules and after that the filters for each rule and build a objects containing all the information. those objects you can then finally validate against a reference list.

Comment: So, to get all enabled blocking inbound tcp rules: `Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object { $_.Action -eq 'Block' -and $_.Direction -eq 'Inbound' -and $_.Enabled -eq $True -and ($_ | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).Protocol -eq 'TCP' }`

Comment: Thank you everyone, the comments have been helpful and I'll use them to make my Powershell script.